# Goto First line of page

Tags: cursor-motions, vim-windows

I know to go to the last line of the page i use `L`.
How do I get to the first line of the page ?
or what is the opposite of `L`

Comment: See also `vimtutor`, for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The opposite of `L` is `H`. From [`:h L`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#L):

```
                                                H
H                       To line [count] from top (Home) of window (default:
                        first line on the window) on the first non-blank
                        character linewise.  See also 'startofline' option.
                        Cursor is adjusted for 'scrolloff' option.

                                                M
M                       To Middle line of window, on the first non-blank
                        character linewise.  See also 'startofline' option.

                                                L
L                       To line [count] from bottom of window (default: Last
                        line on the window) on the first non-blank character
                        linewise.  See also 'startofline' option.
                        Cursor is adjusted for 'scrolloff' option.
```

Comment: As a mnemonic think of `H`, `M`, and `L` as high, middle, and low

Comment: @PeterRincker that's the natural interpretation. Any idea why the help text preferred Home/Middle/Last?